# How to use github graphql v4 api to query all repositories in my organization?

Tags: github, graphql

I wanna query all repositories in my organization on github private, i try to use

```
query {

  organization(login:"my-org-name") {
    id
    name
    url

    repositories(first:100) {
        nodes {
        id
        name
      }

    }

  }
}
```

However it returns

```
{
  "data": {
    "organization": {
      "id": "MDEyOk*********************U4ODUw",
      "name": "my-org-name",
      "url": "https://github.com/my-org-name",
      "repositories": {
        "nodes": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

can't find any repositories. 
I test it on Github Developer, https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/

Answer (score 9):

you can achieve using `search` end point (you need to be authenticated)

```
query myOrgRepos($queryString: String!) {
  search(query: $queryString, type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with query variables

```
{
  "queryString": "org:my_org"
}
```

Note that as expected **you do not get the list repositories of your organization, you get the list of your organization list that you have access**

Comment: With pagination via the `gh api` cli and and org of more than 700 repos this search query takes 15-16 seconds while `organization(login: "***") { repositories(first: 100, after: $endCursor) { nodes { nameWithOwner } pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage }}}}` was (still long) 10 seconds - any idea how to interact in a more timely fashion?

`gh api -X GET '/orgs/***/repos?per_page=100' --paginate` seems much faster at 8 seconds - any idea how to get this info faster?

Answer (score 5):

The GraphQL Explorer is an OAuth Application that needs to be [given permission](https://help.github.com/articles/approving-oauth-apps-for-your-organization/) to access your organization data.

You can grant this access directly for the [GraphQL API Explorer](https://github.com/settings/connections/applications/370acf60ad72187f9599) or navigate to it from your Settings -> Applications -> Authorized OAuth Apps

[image: oauth apps]

**Note** that a [personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) (PAT) does not have this restriction, so this isn't required for an application using your token.

Answer (score 0):

## Here my example.

You have to be Authenticated to do this request.

url: https://api.github.com/graphql

header: Authorization bearer token

method: POST

```
query {
    viewer {
        avatarUrl
        login
        resourcePath
        url
        bio
        company
        createdAt
        location
        followers(first: 100) {
            nodes {
                name
                url
            }
        }
        repositories(first: 100) {
            nodes {
                name
                description
                url
                createdAt
                collaborators(first: 5) {
                    nodes {
                        name  
                    }
                    totalCount
                }
            }
            totalCount
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (type your org instead of `your_org`):

```
    {
  repositoryOwner(login: "your_org") {
    ... on Organization {
      repositories(first: 100) {
        totalCount
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
        }
        nodes {
          id
          name
          stars: stargazerCount
          forks: forkCount
          created_at: createdAt          
          organization: owner {
            login
          }
          repo_url: url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```