# How to test an organization with Github's GraphQL API v4 in Postman?

Tags: graphql, postman, github-api, github-api-v4

Trying to get an orgs private and public repositories in Postman I've attempted:

```
GET: https://api.github.com/graphql
```

Under Authorization selected:

```
Type: Basic Auth
```

I add my Github username to `username` and
for `password` per the docs and I place my [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). For testing purposes I've selected everything for token creation.

Under **Body** I have:

**query**:

```
query ($github_login: String!, $repo_count: Int!) {
  viewer {
    organization(login: $github_login) {
      login
      id
      location
      name
      url
      repositories(first: $repo_count, privacy: PRIVATE, isFork: false) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
          openGraphImageUrl
          createdAt
          stargazerCount
          url
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**variables**:

```
{"github_login": "org-name", "repo_count": 100}
```

my Status is a `200 OK` but my results are not repositories but instead a long listing of `null`:

```
"types": [
                {
                    "kind": "INPUT_OBJECT",
                    "name": "AbortQueuedMigrationsInput",
                    "description": "Autogenerated input type of AbortQueuedMigrations",
                    "fields": null,
                    "inputFields": [
                        {
                            "name": "ownerId",
                            "description": "The ID of the organization that is running the migrations.",
                            "type": {
                                "kind": "NON_NULL",
                                "name": null,
                                "ofType": {
                                    "kind": "SCALAR",
                                    "name": "ID",
                                    "ofType": null
                                }
                            },
                            "defaultValue": null
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "clientMutationId",
                            "description": "A unique identifier for the client performing the mutation.",
                            "type": {
                                "kind": "SCALAR",
                                "name": "String",
                                "ofType": null
                            },
                            "defaultValue": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "interfaces": null,
                    "enumValues": null,
                    "possibleTypes": null
                },
```

In my research I've read:

- [How to use github graphql v4 api to query all repositories in my organization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753738/how-to-use-github-graphql-v4-api-to-query-all-repositories-in-my-organization)
- [Querying with GraphQL](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/graphql/)
- [Postman Github API](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-api-101-with-auth/documentation/)
- [Introduction to GitHub GraphQL API](https://medium.com/vlgunarathne/introduction-to-github-graphql-api-423ebbab75f9)
- [How to create an issue on github using Postman with github api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607272/how-to-create-an-issue-on-github-using-postman-with-github-api)

In Postman how can I get my org repositories with the Github API?

Answer (score 0):

The `viewer` Graphql API returns the user which has been authenticated.

You should instead use the organization API to get the repo list.

**Example Query**

```
query ($github_login: String!, $repo_count: Int!) {
    organization(login: $github_login) {
      login
      id
      location
      name
      url
      repositories(first: $repo_count, privacy: PRIVATE, isFork: false) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
          openGraphImageUrl
          createdAt
          stargazerCount
          url
          description
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```
{"github_login": "org-name", "repo_count": 100}
```

Comment: With the removal of the `viewer` the returned result is still the same as what's in the question.

Comment: I tried with a public org and it is giving me the correct result. https://imgur.com/a/t10ND7T

Comment: As what's mentioned in the question the results aren't being returned in Postman. Both your edited query and the query in the question work in Github's explorer. Also at this moment I'm trying to get private repo data not public.